# Where can I find the folder SegmentationClassRaw when using semantic segmentation?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to learn semantic segmentation to train my own dataset in this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab).

But when I downloaded the voc2012 dataset, I didn't find this folder `SegmentationClassRaw` in voc2012 dataset.

My folder structure is like this：

```
── VOC2012
        ├── Annotations
        ├── ImageSets
        │   ├── Action
        │   ├── Layout
        │   ├── Main
        │   └── Segmentation
        ├── JPEGImages
        ├── SegmentationClass
        └── SegmentationObject
```

So where can I find the folder `SegmentationClassRaw`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to fix it.

Go to this folder `models-master/research/deeplabdatasets`.

Use this command:

> python remove_gt_colormap.py --original_gt_folder=./pascal_voc_seg/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationClass --output_dir=./pascal_voc_seg/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationClassRaw

Then the folder `SegmentationClassRaw` will be generated automatically.